# How to get center point (CGPoint) of a UIView that has been set using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uibezierpath

So I haven't seen any other SO question about this. Basically, I have set a UIView with autolayout, programmatically.

The issue occurs when I try to create a UIBezierPath:

```
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: myView.center, radius: (91*(1.2))/2 - (8/2), startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
```

The issue is that the myView.center prints out: `0.0, 0.0` since I did not set a CGRect .frame for the myView, and instead used autolayout (which is below):

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91),
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91),
    myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: myButton.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1),
    myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: myButton.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 1),
])
```

and also perhaps I should note that myView is added as a subview of myButton (though this shouldn't really matter..)

**So how do I make this work? how could I get the .center (a type CGPoint) to use in the UIBezierPath?** THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations:

1. The `center` property is where the center of the current view is *within the coordinate system of the superview.* That’s not likely what you intended. You want the `CGPoint(x: myView.bounds.midX, y: myView.bounds.midY)`, which is the midpoint of the *current* view.
2. Because you’re using constraints, you need to defer this creation of the path until after the constraints are applied, because that’s when the view’s `bounds` are set. The typical solution is to implement a `UIButton` subclass, and in that subclass you can implement [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews), and set the path there.

For example, a simple circular button might be defined as follows:

```
@IBDesignable
class CircleButton: UIButton {
    let normalColor: UIColor = .red
    let highlightedColor: UIColor = .init(red: 0.5, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = normalColor.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(bounds.height, bounds.width) / 2
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted {
                shapeLayer.fillColor = highlightedColor.cgColor
            } else {
                shapeLayer.fillColor = normalColor.cgColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The virtue of this approach is that:

- Your view controller is not encumbered with lots of code for rendering of circles.
- This will work regardless of size that is rendered (which can be useful if your constraints are not for a fixed size, but might respond to the orientation of the device, size classes, etc.).
- If you want, because this is `@IBDesignable`, you can render it in your storyboards/NIBs.

Comment: I see. I think I should give you some more info: I set the myView autolayout before doing the myView.center of course. Oh ok, in response to the 2.), is it not possible to do something as simple as the myView.center to get a CGPoint for an autolayout view?

Comment: @GEOG - Theoretically if you called `layoutIfNeeded` after setting the constraints, then the `bounds` should be set, and then `bounds.midX` and `bounds.midY` should return correct values. But it’s a tad fragile, not responding to size changes (e.g. if you had the circular view’s constraints proportional to something else on the screen rather than a fixed width and height. But there are a number of ways to accomplish what you want. I’d personally would put it in a button subclass, respond to `layoutSubviews` and you have a nice, flexible, general purpose solution.

Comment: ah yes it was that I did not do the myView.layoutIfNeeded(). It worked now! And thank you also for the class approach too!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using bounds instead of frames. They may help you give the center coordinates of the UIVIew. The center property is where the center of the current view is within the coordinate system of the superview.  You can try to use the below code which is the midpoint of the current view.

```
CGPoint(x: myView.bounds.midX, y: myView.bounds.midY),
```